# Eclipse Birt JVM Terminated Exit code = -1

Tags: eclipse, jvm, birt, terminate

I downloaded birt-report-designer-all-in-one-2_5_0.
enviornment is windows 7, 8gb memory, 64bit OS and jdk1.6.0_45(64 bit)
But while launching , throwing this error

[image: birt error message]

**My eclipse.ini is**

-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.200.v20090520.jar

--launcher.library

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519

-showsplash

org.eclipse.platform

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize

-vmargs

-Xms512m

-Xmx1024m

-vm D:\java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\javaw.exe

Note: the same eclipse which is working perfectly fine in my colleague's machine(with exactly same configuration)

Does anyone have other possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed by installing 32 bit jdk 1.6 (uninstall 64 bit jdk)and pointing JAVA_HOME to this installed folder